# Spring Dynamic data source routing for mongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, mongotemplate

I'm developing a spring web application.
I have 2 types of data sources- mySQL & MongoDB.

I'm using AbstractRoutingDataSource implementation for mysql like in this blog:
https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/

it works great.

I would like to achieve the same for my mongoDB.
Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Interesting, but I don't believe so.

Comment: You could probably extend `SimpleDbFactory` and overwrite `getDb` method using 'AbstractRoutingDataSource' implementation for reference...